# Display fields related to Grouping inside the details section

Tags: crystal-reports

[image: the report grouping that I wish to get]

I need to get a customer wise invoice report. the relationship between customer and invoices is "one customer has many invoice". I grouped the report by customer ID and need to display customer name and other customer related data in the details section which I have used to display invoice related details.
As you can see in the attachment  all the customer related data are displayed in the first column and it is not repeated (It can be set by applying the tick to "Suppress if duplicated" in format object window ). Invoices related to that particular customer (detail part) are displayed from the second column onwards.

Comment: I didn't get your exact problem... what is your problem with the display

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: The grouping cannot be done as same as shown in the image... I want to display the grouping fields in the left column of the details section instead of the "Grouping Section Header"